# Android - Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() setting Config to ARGB_8888

Tags: android, bitmap, config, scaling

This is the first time I have had a question that, despite thorough searching, does not appear to have been asked yet.

I am having an issue with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` whereby the resulting scaled bitmap is always `ARGB_8888`, regardless of the Config of the input. Naturally, this is a problem when working with limited memory.

```
        InputStream is;
    try {
        is = mAssets.open("test.png");
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_4444;
        Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
        System.out.println("Original Config: " + originalBitmap.getConfig());
        mScale = (float) mHeight / originalBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, (int)(mScale*(float)originalBitmap.getWidth()),
                (int)(mScale*(float)originalBitmap.getHeight()), true);
        System.out.println("Scaled: " + mBitmapScaled.getConfig());
        originalBitmap.recycle();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do something.
    }
```

The above code returns the outputs:

> Original Bitmap: ARGB_4444
>
> Scaled: ARGB_8888

As the `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` method does not take a Config, there does not appear to be a way to prevent this. Any ideas?

Comment: If your original bitmap contains alpha, ARGB_8888 will be returned. Otherwise RGB_565. Don't use `createScaledBitmap` if you don't want ARGB_8888, e.g. use `Canvas`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`createScaledBitmap(...)` creates a new, scaled Bitmap and therefore passes in your supplied arguments to the `createBitmap(...)` method.

The following is a [snippet](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/428955614836c4a51737e8ff9d4b653c5a80eecd/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#L690-L705) from the source code of `createBitmap(...)`:

```
    if (config != null) {
        switch (config) {
            case RGB_565:
                newConfig = Config.RGB_565;
                break;
            case ALPHA_8:
                newConfig = Config.ALPHA_8;
                break;
            //noinspection deprecation
            case ARGB_4444:
            case ARGB_8888:
            default:
                newConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Every Bitmap with the `ARGB_4444` configuration gets converted to an `ARGB_8888` Bitmap as you can see. So to answer your question: No, there is no way to prevent this (unless you want to copy parts of the Bitmap.java source code and create your own scaling method).

**Why do Bitmaps with the `ARGB_4444` configuration get converted to `ARGB_8888`?**

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) states it like this:

> `ARGB_4444`:
>
> This field is deprecated. Because of the poor quality of this
>   configuration, it is advised to use `ARGB_8888` instead.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, very informative. I would up-vote this but I do not yet have the required reputation. I will be sure to come back and do so when I have.